# Golang: Element-wise division on a slice

Tags: go, data-science, lapack, blas, scientific-computing

Element-wise operations are faster in python(through numpy) and matlab (./) than using a for-loop. They use BLAS/LAPAC for this, i think.

Currently im using a for-loop for iterating through a slice. Is it possible to get element-wise operations for slices? Will it be faster then?

Comment: optimized packages like BLAS/LAPAC will usually be faster, but you have to test. There are a lot of packages available under gonum: https://godoc.org/gonum.org/v1/gonum

Comment: Cross-posted: Element-wise operations on slices : https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/91h87u/elementwise_operations_on_slices/